I got this error! OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application :c
I trying to run an Python file today and got this error below! Anyone know what's issue and the solution to fix it?
(local) C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local>python 1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local\1.py", line 257, in <module>
    driver = initDriver()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local\1.py", line 23, in initDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self._start_process(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\local\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 208, in _start_process
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida

i have this code in 1.py
import os
import time
import string
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

TARGET_URL: str = "www.xd.com"
list1 = ["350","300","320","310","340","330","360","305"]

def initDriver():
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--incognito")
    #option.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)
    return driver

I try change the webdrivermanager

You can avoid the install mechanism in modern Python / selenium environments as follows:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

def initDriver():
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Platform:
python 3.12.5
selenium 4.23.1

Note:
This answer does not support the idea of using a function to do this. Better to use a context manager

Ty bro this fix my problem
